# Android Webview text-shadow display

Tags: android, css, webview

I have searched google and stackoverflow but I can't find any mention of this problem.

I am using an android webview in an app.

It wrongly displays a css text-shadow. The text is displayed and the shadow is displayed about 30px above the text.

Even a simple text-shadow such as [simple text-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-shadow) displays red text about 30px above the text.

i.e. text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;

I am using android 4.4.

Does anyone know why this happens?

I'm not allowed to post images so here is a link to an example:
[example](http://bizapps.co.uk/temp/text-shadow.jpg)

Comment: Also had this problem...

Comment: me, too. Weird there is no documented fix to this yet

Comment: I have just encountered this issue. Is there a fix/work-around for Android 4.2?

Comment: I have logged this on the Android issue tracker, seeing as you hadn't :) https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187264 Please star it.